# Sublime Text 2 + Emmet - not expanding correctly

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

I have installed emmet for Sublime Text 2...
And it works - kind a strange way
When I enter `d` it starts showing possibilities, but as soon as I press: `:` emmet shows completely different tip:

```
b (bottom)
```

So I need to press esc to close fuzzysearch box and press tab to allow Emmet do what it is used to do.

Dow, if I don't press esc before the tab key the resould is: `d:bottom:`, is I press esc, it desoults in correct: `display:block`.

Do you have an idea how can i fix that?

Comment: Can you provide more info about your issue? The `:` character is not a valid prefix character so Emmet can’t either autocomplete or provide different snippet for such case

Comment: From the chat sheet:
`d:b` should expand to `display:block;`. I have added explanation to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because Emmet tries to respect default ST completions and due to lack of API support to properly handle built-in snippets: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#tab-key-handler

By default, Emmet will not expand abbreviations by Tab if there’s autocomplete popup visible to allow users to work with default ST completions and snippets. You can override this behavior:

1. Go to `Preferences > Settings — User`
2. Add `"disable_tab_abbreviations_on_auto_complete": false` option. Make sure this file contains valid JSON.

After that everything should work fine, but you’ll no longer able to complete items from autocomplete popup with Tab key, use Enter key instead.

Comment: @sergey any idea why .classname>span doesn't work in latest build i see some error when loading plugins though

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue but my fix was different to that of the accepted answer.

I had to go to Preferences > Settings — User and remove "emmet" from the ignored packages and everything started working again!

Comment: Solved my problem as well and a problem for a different plugin. I couldn't figure out why color highlighter wasn't working until now haha. Thanks!