# Sublime Text 2 + Emmet - Expansion doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext2, fuzzy-search, emmet

I have the Emmet Plugin on Sublime Text 2, and for example, in a CSS file, pressing TAB after:

```
pos:r
```

*should* result in

```
position:relative
```

But instead, after the `:`, the fuzzy search changes completely and disregards whatever was before the `:`.

This is very similar to this question:

[Sublime Text 2 + Emmet - not expanding correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535981/sublime-text-2-emmet-not-expanding-correctly)

, but I have tried adding `"disable_tab_abbreviations_on_auto_complete": false` in valid JSON format, saved, restarted ST2, but the behaviour is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a couple of things here. They fixed the problem for me:

1. Save the file in ".css" format
2. After typing `pos:r` press `Ctrl (Cmd) + E`

Hope this helps.